# Use base url for image source html/js

Tags: javascript, html, image, src

Hey i get my html content via json. The image blocks look like:

```
src=\"/2017/03/test.jpg\" alt=\"test\" width=\"576\" height=\"800\" srcset=\"/2017/03/test.jpg 576w, /2017/03/test-112x155.jpg 112w, /2017/03/test-432x600.jpg 432w\"
```

The src should look like mywebsite.com/img-src but it looks like localhost/img-src right now...

I tried to replace it via JavaScript but then it looks like: localhost/mywebsite.com/img-src

Does somebody have an idea

Edit: the image is hosted on ONE Website! And it should be shown on every device. Now its 404...

Comment: I'm unclear about what the problem is. May you edit your question to be clearer?

Comment: Either append the URL before it populates the source of your image, or use JS to find all the images and change their source to include it.

Comment: I would suggest do not touch ``src``. If server returns response like this then it is meant to look like this. Instead, if you're working on ``localhost`` create virtual host, for example ``dev.mysite.com`` configure Apache to point it to subfolder, for example ``/var/www/html/mysite/img-src``

Answer (score 4):

It can be done by including a `<base>` tag in the `<head>` tag like this:

`<base href="mywebsite.com/path">`

For more information reference this webpage: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp